# shiny add Progress bar with source() function

Tags: r, progress-bar, shiny

At the start of my shiny application, I run a source function to load and process my data.

Everything is ok, but when user start the application, there is a loading time of about 10 seconds.  I would like to add a progress bar.

I saw tutorials, but always integrated with an observe or reactive function, which is not my case.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  source("/srv/shiny-server/Data_base/import.r")    
})
```

How to add a progress bar ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link helps: https://github.com/daattali/shiny-server/blob/master/loading-screen/app.R

Basically you should add this code outside reactive content:

```
 appCSS <- "
#loading-content {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
"
```

This to ui side:

```
useShinyjs(),
inlineCSS(appCSS),

# Loading message
div(
  id = "loading-content",
  h2("Loading...")
),
```

And this to the server side (will hide "loading" message after content has been loaded:

```
 hide(id = "loading-content", anim = TRUE, animType = "fade")
```

Comment: Note that the link to my loading screen app has been taken down. You can access the code (and an explanation of it) here: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/loading-screen